# Using CSS to calculate a gradient between two hex colors

Tags: javascript, css, gradient

I am working on a project for myself for a Raspberry pi MagicMirror (found on github, thanks to everyone who helped make it possible/available!) and I'm working on my own tweaks for it. In case you aren't familiar, it uses Javascript and CSS.

I have been customizing a temperature module that pulls from the Dark Skies API (https://darksky.net/dev/) and would like to figure out how to get a CSS bar between the min temp and max temp to be colored in a gradient between the two temperatures. For example:

mintemp(blue) [ . . . . . . . . . . . . ] maxtemp(orange)

I'd like to get the middle bar to go from, for sake of argument, #00FFD7 to #E05700. What do I need to code for this? Would like a generic formula to calculate the colors from the variables. Here is my relevant code:

```
var minTemp = document.createElement("span");
minTemp.innerHTML = rowMinTemp + "&deg;";           
        if(rowMinTemp <=0) {
            minTemp.className = "customComment max-tempU0";
        }
        else if (rowMinTemp <=20) {
            minTemp.className = "customComment max-temp20";
        }
        else if (rowMinTemp <=30) {
            minTemp.className = "customComment max-temp30";
        }
        else if (rowMinTemp <=40) {
            minTemp.className = "customComment max-temp40";
        }
        else if (rowMinTemp <=50) {
            minTemp.className = "customComment max-temp50";
        }
        else if (rowMinTemp <=60) {
            minTemp.className = "customComment max-temp60";
        }
        else if (rowMinTemp <=70) {
            minTemp.className = "customComment max-temp70";
        }
        else if (rowMinTemp <=80) {
            minTemp.className = "customComment max-temp80";
        }   
        else {
            minTemp.className = "customComment max-temp90";
        }

var maxTemp = document.createElement("span");
maxTemp.innerHTML = rowMaxTemp + "&deg;";
//maxTemp.className = "temp max-temp";
        if (rowMaxTemp <= 0) {
            maxTemp.className = "customComment max-tempU0";             
        }
        else if (rowMaxTemp <= 20) {
            maxTemp.className= "customComment max-temp20";
        }   
        else if (rowMaxTemp <= 30) {
            maxTemp.className= "customComment max-temp30";
        }
        else if (rowMaxTemp <= 40) {
            maxTemp.className= "customComment max-temp40";
        }
        else if (rowMaxTemp <= 50) {
            maxTemp.className= "customComment max-temp50";
        }
        else if (rowMaxTemp <= 60) {
            maxTemp.className= "customComment max-temp60";
        }
        else if (rowMaxTemp <= 70) {
            maxTemp.className= "customComment max-temp70";
        }
        else if (rowMaxTemp <= 80) {
            maxTemp.className= "customComment max-temp80";
        }
        else {
            maxTemp.className= "customComment max-temp90";
        }

var bar = document.createElement("span");
bar.className = "bar";
bar.innerHTML = "&nbsp;"
var barWidth = Math.round(interval * (rowMaxTemp - rowMinTemp));
bar.style.width = barWidth + '%';
```

Let me know if I'm missing something that is needed. Thanks!

Comment: I think I'm not following the question completely. What function do you need that prevents you from using background: linear-gradient(90deg, #00FFD7, #E05700);

Comment: I guess I'm just not familiar enough with coding that I know how to implement that in my javascript file. Using your hint here, I'd need to know how to color the bar object by passing minTemp and maxTemp to it

Comment: I don't want it to just reference the static codes, I want it to pull from whatever value minTemp and maxTemp are when it's rendered. So setting the gradient colors to #00FFD7 and #E05700 wouldn't be correct for any temperatures that are outside of those ranges.